# How to prove this form of $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, contest-math

> Show that every positive integer is a sum of one or more numbers of the form $2^r3^s,$ where $r$ and $s$ are nonnegative integers and no summand divides another.

From: [AOPS Putnam A1 Solution](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h64429p383273)

I see they mean that:

$$n-1 = \sum_{k=1}^{x} 2^{r_k} 3^{s_k}$$

By induction hypothesis. Then:

$$n = \sum_{k=1}^{x} 2^{r_k} 3^{s_k} + 1$$

Then how to proceed by $n/2$? How can you say that:

$$\frac{n}{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{x} 2^{r_k} 3^{s_k} $$

Where did the $1$ go? And how can you assume it works for $\frac{n}{2}$ (the hypothesis)?

Comment: This question is just a joke. Note that $\frac{n}{2}$ is not always an integer and then the statement does not have to be true. For any integer $n$ you can just make it a sum of $n$ $1$'s , $1+1+$...$+1$, since $1 = 2^03^0$.

Comment: You can't have $1$ in the sum, because it is a divisor of all the others.

Answer (score 2):

If $3$ is a factor of $n$, there is a solution that follows from $n/3$.
For example, to solve $21$, take your solution $3+4$ for seven, and multiply by $3$ to get $9+12$.
Otherwise, either $n-2^m$ or $n-2^{m+1}$ is a multiple of 3, for some $m$ with $2^m>n/4$.
All future terms will have the factor $3$ in them.
For example, for $31$, take $31-16=15$, divide by 3, and you now have to solve for $5$.  Since $5=2+3$, it follows that $15=6+9$, and $31=6+9+16$.
You are left with trying to solve $(n-2^m)/3$ or $(n-2^{m+1})/3$, both of which are less than $n/4$ and therefore less than $2^m$.
All future terms are multiples of 3, so they are not factors of $2^m$, and they are less than $2^m$, so $2^m$ is not a factor of them.

Comment: what is the induction hypothesis?

Comment: I guess, suppose that all $m<n$ have solutions.  Starting with $n=1$, which has the solution $n=2^03^0$ (and is the only one that includes $1$ as one of its terms).

Comment: Then how do you prove $P(n+1)$? moreover, what is $P(n+1)$? (+1) by the way

Comment: I proved $P(n)$ assuming all $P(m), m<n$.  By renaming the number $n$, that is the same as proving $P(n+1)$ assuming all $P(m),m\leq n$.  I use either $P((n+1)/3)$, or $P((n+1-2^m)/3)$ or $P((n+1-2^{m+1})/3)$, depending on $n+1$