# Putnam 2005 A1 Solution

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, contest-math

> Show that every positive integer is a sum of one or more numbers of the form $2^r3^s,$ where $r$ and $s$ are nonnegative integers and no summand divides another.
>   (For example, $23=9+8+6.)$

Suppose for $k = \{1, 2, 3... ,n-1\}$ this equality holds.

Let $n$ be an even integer. Since $\frac{n}{2} \le n -1$ if $n \ge 2$ then,

$$\frac{n}{2} = \sum 2^x 3^y \implies n = \sum 2^{x+1} 3^{y}$$

Proof hold for $P(n)$ from $P(n-1)$.

With odds, it gets trickier.

Suppose $n$ is a odd integer, **NOT PRIME.** So:

$$n = \{1, 9, 15, ...\}$$

Since, $\frac{n}{3} \le n-1 $ if $n \ge 3$ It follows,

$$\frac{n}{3} = \sum 2^x e^y \implies n = \sum 2^x 3^{y+1}$$

Suppose $n$ is **PRIME.**

$$n = \{3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, ...  \}$$

There exists $t$ such that:

$$n < 3^{t-1} \implies \log_{3}(n) < t-1 = \sum 2^x 3^{y}$$

By strong induction,

$$\log_{3}(n) = \sum 2^x 3^y$$

Is there any thing I can do now ?I am stuck!

Comment: $25$ is not prime, odd, and not divisible by $3$. So is $35$, $49$, etc. And $\log_3(n)$ is an integer for only one prime $n$.

Comment: Dupe of [question yesterday.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1172035/242)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your start is right, but odd numbers that are not prime are not all divisible by $3$.

Rather, you need to first show that if $n$ is divisible by $3$ or $2$, then you can proceed inductively. That is what you have (sort of) done already.

If $n$ is not divisible by $3$ or $2$, pick the largest, $k$, such that $n-2^k$ is positive and divisible by $3$. This will alway (why?) be either $k=\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor$ or $k=\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor-1$, which means that $4\cdot 2^k > n$.

Then proceed by induction using $\frac{n-2^k}{3}$. Since $\frac{n-2^k}{3}<2^k$, none of the terms are multiples of $2^k$. Multiply those terms by $3$ and then include $2^k$.

**Lemma:** Prove that if $n,m$ are both not divisible by $3$, then one of $n-m$ or $n-2m$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Why will it always be $k = \floor \log_2( \floor$? I mean. $2^{\log_2(n)} = n$ but that is different from the floor part. (+1)

Comment: @Amad27 The lemma at the bottom is a hint. There is always an $j$ so that $\frac{n}2<2^j<n$ (since $n$ is odd, we have strict inequality.) This $j$ is $\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$. Now, in the Lemma, let $m=2^{j-1}$.

Comment: Here's a question. How can you guarantee that $n - 2^k$ is divisible by $3$ for some $k$?

Comment: @Amad27 Again, see the lemma, and my previous comment, or just think about it modulo $3$ - if $n$ is not divisible by $3$ then one of $n-2$ or $n-4$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Okay. Since, $$n - 2^k > 0 \implies n > 2^k$$ Now I have to prove that: $$\frac{n - 2^k}{3} < 2^k \implies n - 2^k < 2^k + 2^k + 2^k \implies n < (2^{k+2})$$ Now the question is, how do I show this? Well, of course there actually has to be SOME integer (because $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above) so that that inequality is true? Is this how you would explain? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Amad27 No offense, but I assume you are trying to answer an old Putnam question in order to get better at answering this type of question. I specifically left out a lot of details so that you could try to fill them in. The remaining steps are elementary number theory, and I recommend that you review that topic.

Comment: None taken. Yes, I am trying to get better. I just need help confirming things, which is why I ask in the comments.